# Samsung Smart TV app dev using player

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I can't understand how to get and use player in the app, no one method in D-forum works for me.
I have list of channels in my app, and need to play them as playlist.

Can you give me the link with working docs about getting and using player?

Javascript application using AppsFramework

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here, step by step guide on how to play a set of videos!

http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/tut00055/index.html